# Read double values numbers from a file into a vector in C++ and access their values

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I am trying to read two numbers of double values stored on same line separated by comma from a text file or csv file into a vector. The numbers are stored in this format like this [1688.37, 115.14]. I would like to read this numbers from the file and then store in array so can access the first and second number. My code compiles but will not display the numbers. Here the code in C++.

```
ifstream file("C:/arrow1.txt",ios::app);
double s;
std::vector<double> data;
while(file>>s){
data.push_back(s);
              }
   for(int i=0; i<data.size(); i++){
   std::cout<<data[i]<<std::endl;
              }
```

This code reads and displays the numbers but in same line as string. Then I don't know how to access the first and second number

```
ifstream fh("C:/arrow1.csv",ios::app);
std::vector<std::string> vs;
std::string s;
while(fh>>s){
   vs.push_back(s);
}
for(int i=0; i<vs.size(); i++){
   std::cout<<vs[i]<<std::endl;
}
```

Any help?

Comment: Can you add sample file contents and format the code properly.

Comment: I dont understand what should I add? ?

Comment: I have to say that the numbers stored in the file are unknown. A they are coming  from the output from other program but I dont know what is going to be the output.

Answer (score 1):

You could use your second attempt in combination with `atof()`([Have a look here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atof/)). It converts a `string` into `double`.

Copy the first number into a second string and then use `atof()` to get your double value.

Example:

```
// Your copied values from the file
std::string s1 = "[1688.37,";
std::string s2 = "115.14]";

// Copy the number without "[" and ",", the length of the number is variable
std::string str1 = s1.substr(1, s1.length()-1); // Copy the first number in str1
double firstNum = atof(str1.c_str());
cout << firstNum << endl;

// Copy the second number without "]"
std::string str2 = s2.substr(0, s2.length()-1); // Copy the second number in str2
double secondNum = atof(str2.c_str());
cout << secondNum << endl;
```

Comment: The `>>` operator for `std::string` uses whitespace to parse text. So, using OP's example "[1688.37, 115.14]", the `std::string` instances added to the vector in the second code sample will be  "[1688.37," and  "115.14]". So, the strings are not ready for `atof()` at this point.

Comment: I tried but have error using atof(). Can anybody give me the right code how to use it?

Comment: @GigaRohan that's why i recommended to copy the number into a second string. I think that's the easiest way to get rid of the `[],`

Comment: but if I copy the number in the second string I will get [1688.37,. So how to get rid of " [ " and " , " ?

Comment: @user3035413 Added an example. Is this enough?

Comment: but the numbers are unknown. I got this number from other program output. So how can I use std::string s = "[1688.37, 115.14]"; when dont know which numbers are stored in the file?

Comment: @izlin I dont have any prior  information about the numbers. They are unknown numbers, actually represent some pixel coordinates of a center of some detected object in the image. B

Comment: @user3035413 But you have the format, don't you? It doesn't matter if there is `[1, 2]` or `[4.123475, 98172]` in the file because i read from the first element to the last one. Is it the format that varies or what exactly is your problem?

Comment: Yes, I have the format. The format is always the same[ double_number1, double_number2]

Comment: And as long as you use that format my example will return the two double values. Just try using different values with this example, I tested it online and it worked.

Comment: ok . got it. In this case    std::string s1 = vs[0];  std::string s2 = vs[1];

Answer (score 1):

If the `istream` (be it `stringstream`, `ifstream`) declared as `s` in the following example contains a well-defined pattern of any number of lines of the format `[float1, float2]` - you can use the `>>` operator (stream extraction operator in this case) on the stream to read the values and the `get` call to read the `,`, `[`, `]` and `newline` characters, like in the following example:

```
std::vector<double> fpvec;
char c;
double in;
while( s.eof() == false)
{
    s.get(c);
    s >> in;
    fpvec.push_back(in);
    s.get(c);
    s >> in;
    fpvec.push_back(in);
    s.get(c);
    s.get(c);

    // Print last two inserted elements - testing purposes only
    unsigned int size = fpvec.size();
    std::cout << fpvec[size-2] <<" and "<< fpvec[size-1] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: @user3035413 - without the '[', the ',' and the ']' characters, I guess? Output should be '1688.37 and 115.14' if you only have one line with two doubles separated by comma and the line is wrapped with [ and ]. Check this out: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp11_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMNThaS2tNZlFuanM

Comment: @user3035413 And you got the numbers in the fpvec vector! Isn't this what you asked for??

Comment: Yes. Thanks @ll fot valuable answers

Comment: @user3035413 Both ifstream and stringstream have istream as a base and the code which I provide can be used with either of them.

Comment: sorry. One more thing. How would be the code if the file  have two lines with two numbers.                      Let we say the file format is like this                                                                                               [1874.2, 244.465]                 [1453.13, 246.315]. The first line is [1874.2, 244.465] and then second line with  [1453.13, 246.315]. So looks like matrix 2x2

Comment: I check it and it does not work. Its gives me 0 and 0 output.